# JS click event notation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working through some code a previous developer has written and have came across the following notation:

```
'.js-enter-new-address click'() {}
```

The code works but I dont understand why. Can anyone point me to any documentation of how this works? as i've not come across js written in this form before. I would usually expect it to be:

```
$('.js-enter-new-address').on('click', function(event) {}
```

**Update** 
I've noticed this code is part of the following, Please see below:

```
    const deliveryAddressComponent = Component.create('.checkout-delivery-address', { 
'.js-enter-new-address click'() {},
});
```

Comment: The first one is not valid syntax as you're calling a string as a function. You must be missing something.

Comment: Are you certain that's the syntax used? While it's technically possible to invoke the string constructor, it doesn't work like that, and even if it did following it with braces would be a syntax error. The only thing I can think is that there's some kind of transpiler converting that code to jQuery/JS. However I don't see the point doing all of that just to save 7 characters

Comment: You're right, I didn't mean to infer that's what this code does. Perhaps badly worded on my part

Comment: Thanks for the replys @RoryMcCrossan, I've updated the code to include an extra bit I've noticed

Comment: Thanks @Aplet123 You are correct it appears to be part of the component.create logic, but again I can't find any information about how this works.

Comment: Which framework is being used? Angular, React and even C# ASP.Net has Component objects which can be created in similar ways to what you've shown

Comment: JS object keys can contain spaces in it and can include "methods" like this `{ foo() { ... } }`. What you have shown is a mix of these.

Comment: Multiple languages is used on the project @RoryMcCrossan as its SAP Hybris. Main code base is Java but I know angular is also used in various areas of the project.

Answer (score 1):

Its part of a javascript object that is send as a parameter of the create function of the Component object.

I don't know what this Component is or does since it's not native js.

Although the definition of the javascript object parameter seems weird it does seem to work as you can see in the snippet below.

```js
var obj =  { 
'.js-enter-new-address click'() {},
}

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: The syntax uses javascript's method in an object shorthand, where you can provide a name, list of parameters, and function body.

Comment: Thank you at least I usedstand why it works now, I will investigate further to see if I can find out what the component does. Thanks You everyone for your help.